# limit growl notifications (failures only) from Cucumber (using guard, spork, ruby_gntp)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, spork, guard

How can I stop certain Cucumber messages from appearing in Growl?  e.g. pending steps or notifications indicating success.  I only want to be interrupted if I've broken something.

Comment: What are you using for displaying messages in Growl?

Comment: The messages are coming from Cucumber ([cucumber-rails](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails)).

Comment: Cucumber itself AFAIK doesn't support Growl by default.

Comment: Sorry I tried to edit my comment but was too late.  I'm not sure how things are flowing from Cucumber but I'm using [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) to watch the filesystem and run Cucumber scenarios and [Spork](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork) as the testing server.

Comment: It looks like Guard is passing the messages to Growl and there has been some work on this issue [here](https://github.com/guard/guard/issues/126) and [here](https://github.com/guard/guard/pull/51).  Thanks for getting me at least looking in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code, there is currently no way of doing this.

Edit:

As Chris himself found out:

Mmm, actually I think you put me on the right track. Since I'm using ruby_gntp, [it looks like like I should be able to disable different notification types](https://github.com/guard/guard/issues/126#issuecomment-2383764) via the Growl GUI. However when I do that, ruby_gntp is raising an exception at its line# 125. I've emailed the author to see what he thinks.

Comment: Mmm, actually I think you put me on the right track.  Since I'm using ruby_gntp, [it looks like like I should be able to disable different notification types](https://github.com/guard/guard/issues/126#issuecomment-2383764) via the Growl GUI.  However when I do that, ruby_gntp is raising an exception at its line# 125.  I've emailed the author to see what he thinks.

Comment: Cool. I've looked at the Guard code and couldn't tell any way of accessing which level you wanted to report, so though it should not be possible.

Comment: I'm gonna give you the bounty since you put me on the right trail.  I'll update the post if I can get any farther than I have.  Thx again.

Comment: Thanks! I'll update the answer with your findings so if someone bumps into this.